# Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, procedure, cursor, constraint

Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida, ou somente me mostrasse o caminho.

Existe uma tabela chamada Questionario a partir dela eu pego os registros em uma procedure e organizo os dados nela.

Aqui está meu código:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`myroot`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_OrganizaEnvioPesquisa`()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE registrantsIds INT DEFAULT 0;

        DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT RegistrantId FROM db_didyoubuy.Questionario GROUP BY RegistrantId;

        DECLARE CONTINUE handler FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows := TRUE;

        OPEN cur;

        questoes : LOOP

        FETCH cur into registrantsIds;
            IF no_more_rows THEN
                leave questoes;
            CLOSE cur;
        END IF;

        INSERT IGNORE INTO db_didyoubuy.Grupo (GrupoId, RegistrantIdReferencia) SELECT UUID(), registrantsIds;
        COMMIT;

        INSERT IGNORE INTO db_didyoubuy.QuestionarioENV (IdQuestionario, NomeDestinatario, EmailDestinatario, TelefoneDestinatario, GrupoId, DataVisita,
        DataEnvio, DataResposta, RegistrantId, HeadingId, HeadingName, CompanyId, CompanyName, TipoVisita, TotalAdPoints, AWSMessageId)  
        SELECT
             Id AS IdQuestionario,
             NomeDestinatario,
             EmailDestinatario,
             TelefoneDestinatario,
             (select GrupoId from db_didyoubuy.Grupo where RegistrantIdReferencia = registrantsIds) as Grupo,
             DataVisita,
             now() AS DataEnvio,
             now() AS DataResposta,      
             RegistrantId,
             HeadingId,
             HeadingName,
             CompanyId,
             CompanyName,
             TipoVisita,
             TotalAdPoints,
             UUID() AS AWSMessageId
         FROM
         db_didyoubuy.Questionario
         WHERE RegistrantId = registrantsIds ORDER BY TotalAdPoints DESC LIMIT 5;  
        COMMIT;

        END LOOP questoes;    

        CLOSE cur;    

    END;
```

Depois de executar a procedure e mandar um show warnings, me retorna o seguinte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso fazer uma inserção de um para muitos. No caso um GUID (UUID) da tabela Grupo para a QuestionarioENV.

O que eu faço primeiro é uma busca de todos os meus usuários(RegistrantId) na tabela Questionario, e para cada um deles eu insiro na tabela Grupo em seguida esse mesmo Guid inserido na tabela Grupo eu relaciono para o mesmo usuário(RegistrantId).

O engraçado é que quando eu gero os primeiros inserts na minha tabela QuestionarioENV ele insere normal, na segunda vez que eu preciso rodar a mesma procedure, ele me retorna o erro.

"Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails";

Minha base sobre sql é bem básica, gostaria de uma luz de como eu poderia corrigir essa procedure ou como eu poderia reescreve-la.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Pode escrever um título que resuma seu problema? A mensagem de erro já está na descrição e não explica realmente do que sua pergunta trata.

Comment: parece que está acontecendo um erro no primeiro `INSERT IGNORE`, pois o valor que causa o erro da pergunta é resultado da sub-consulta que busca o mesmo valor inserido, tente incluir um `SHOW WARNING`

Comment: Sanção se eu colocasse algo como auto incremento resolveria? Eu preciso fazer a inserção de um pra muitos, o guid que eu crio no grupo eu preciso relacionar ele no insert debaixo. Não manjo muito de banco, você tem alguma ideia de como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Coloque seu código aqui em sua pergunta, os links to pastebin são temporários, em algum tempo sua questão não terá código! Para formatar basta adicionar 4 espaços em branco antes de cada linha!

Comment: Jorge os links do pastebin tem a opção de colocar como expires never. Obrigado pelo toque.